# Can ozone be used to efficiently sanitize respiratory or surgical masks against COVID-19?

Tags: covid-19, face-mask-respirator

I read on {1} that:

> ozone in a mobile apparatus could be used to decontaminate rooms in health care facilities, hotels and other buildings.

Can ozone be used to efficiently sanitize respiratory or surgical masks?

---

References:

- {1} Development of a Practical Method for Using Ozone Gas as a Virus Decontaminating Agent
  James B. Hudson, Manju Sharma & Selvarani Vimalanathan. Pages 216-223 | Received 30 Jun 2008, Accepted 26 Nov 2008, Published online: 27 May 2009. https://doi.org/10.1080/01919510902747969

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://qr.ae/pNvp6g

Answer (score 1):

Apparently yes. The South China Morning Post reports that Professor Yuen Kwok-yung of HKU has been using ozone for respirator sterilization: https://www.scmp.com/news/hong-kong/health-environment/article/3078195/coronavirus-hong-kong-scientists-look